# Structure of bootloader

Tags: operating-systems, bootloader

How actually bootloader works? I know that bootloader is somewhere on some non-volatile memory, when we turn on computer, bootloader is loaded into RAM, and his job is to load OS into RAM. How can program that small (32kb or 64kb I think) load hole OS?